# why my format always alerts error,when I use simpledateFormate

Tags: java, android

The date string is: `"Wed Jul 31 14:15:52 +0800 2013"`,my format string is:`"E LLL d HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"`,but it always alert errors at background.

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Jul 31 18:14:47 +0800
>   2013" (at offset 0)

can someone tell me where is fault in my format string?

Answer (score 2):

The correct format is `"E MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"` . There was an illegal character in the format which was `L`

**EDIT:**

As per @Reimeus's comment, android supports `L` in the format as it uses another version of [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). So `L` should have been `LLL` ?

Comment: `L` is fine for android's [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I thought android uses the `java.text.SimpleDeteFormatter`

Comment: it still alert same error,according to the error,it says:"at offset 0"

Answer (score 0):

You should study java.text.SimpleDateFormat API and use only allowed pattern letters. L is not allowed.

Comment: The [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) seems to disagree

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), your `Date` pattern is fine to match the input `String` `Wed Jul 31 18:14:47 +0800 2013`.

Check your actual code to ensure that you are using this pattern. In particular look at the input `String` and the pattern used in the first date field. The error offset `0` indicates the mismatch is occurring here.

It may be that there is mismatch between the deployed code and the input `Date` `String`